# no data display into ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked

Tags: angular, bar-chart, ngx-bootstrap

I have data from web service (nb Info, Warning) from a resolver
and I try to display it in a bar chart but nothing is displayed
the problem I think in the structure of the result [],
I'm blocked for 2 days and I have not found a solution yet.

this is my component.ts

```html
        this.nbWarning = this.route.snapshot.data.analyse.nbWarning.length;
        this.nbInfo = this.route.snapshot.data.analyse.nbInfo.length;

        this.widget = {
            xAxis: true,
            yAxis: true,
            gradient: false,
            legend: false,
            showXAxisLabel: true,
            xAxisLabel: 'Type',
            showYAxisLabel: true,
            yAxisLabel: 'Nombre',
            scheme: {domain: ['#f77509', '#fda76e', '#c7b42c', '#AAAAAA']},
            result: [],

            onSelect: (ev) => {
                console.log(ev);
            }
        };

        this.widget.result.push( this.nbInfo, this.nbWarning);
```

this is my componenet.html

```html
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start start">

        <div class="h-420 my-16" fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100">
            <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
                *fuseIfOnDom
                [scheme]="widget.scheme"
                [results]="widget.result[0]"
                [gradient]="widget.gradient"
                [xAxis]="widget.xAxis"
                [yAxis]="widget.yAxis"
                [legend]="widget.legend"
                [showXAxisLabel]="widget.showXAxisLabel"
                [showYAxisLabel]="widget.showYAxisLabel"
                [xAxisLabel]="widget.xAxisLabel"
                [yAxisLabel]="widget.yAxisLabel"
                (select)="widget.onSelect($event)">
            </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry but result is empty and I don't know how you take the data. Call some api? where ? now result is normal that is empty

Comment: @Doflamingo19 the result since api service with resolve and i ake it into result

Comment: So you are sure that the result after you call API is difference from []?

Comment: [Palash Toshniwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8342668) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066087) saying "The ngx dev is working on it.
keep yourself updated here https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/636"

Answer (score 0):

your result should be in the format of

```
export interface singleBarDataResult= [{ name: string; value: number}];
```